# Issues with angular promises $q.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am having an issue with $q.all in angular which is that I am not getting the response when the code block runs twice. Here's the snippet:

```
           $q.all([
                editSchdBkSrv.getFirstApi(args).then(function (response) {
                    myCtrl.firstApi = response;
                }),
                editSchdBkSrv.getSecondApi(args).then(function (response) {
                    myCtrl.secondApi = response;
                }),
                editSchdBkSrv.getThirdApi(args).then(function(response){
                    myCtrl.thirdApi = response;
                })
            ]).then(function(){
                myCtrl.loader = false;
                someFunction();
            });
```

This code runs when a button is clicked on the form. First time it runs fine and I am able to get all data from all of the API, but when this gets called for the second time, I am not able to get the data from atleast one of the API and majority of the time, one API gets stuck and the browser gets unresponsive.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: how you are calling this code? on `ng-click`/jQuery click event?

Comment: ng-click calls a function which broadcast an event and when the event is recieved, this code gets executed.

Comment: could you please add plunkr/fiddle by demonstrating your problem?

Comment: this sounds like a backend problem. one of your promise is not being fulfilled. add an error function with `e` as error param then debug the response you receive from backend.

Comment: if you don't get any errors then you should dig deeper into the backend since it probably crashes and it doesn't send the client a message back about the crash.